# Allow end user to choose sorting method

Tags: views

How can I allow an end-user (site visitor) to choose a view sorting method themselves?

Or more specifically have the visitor choose Ascending or Descending based on an integer?

[image]

Comment: Which handler are you using, the format that you choose. If you poke around in the settings for say table you will see a choice for allowing sorting and you can make those choice by fields. There are other ways to sort but we would need to know the format you are using to get this information to you.

Comment: Rendered Entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a checkbox "Expose this sort to visitors, to allow them to change it" in the "Configure sort criterion" window[image]

Comment: I tried this. It seems like the only change is that it gives content creators the option to choose through panelizer rather than an anonymous visitor. Or maybe I am missing something still.

Comment: I was missing something. I had " Use exposed widgets form as pane configuration" checked in "Allow Settings". This prevented the exposed filter from being displayed.